# Selenium tests sometimes throws exception

Tags: selenium, grails, spock, geb

I have a strange problem when running my selenium test in grails. I am using geb and spock. My tests run sometimes ok, sometimes not. I don't can reproduce the error.

The exception says, that an at checker fails. But the element is loaded on the page. Has someone ever faced a similar problem?

I don't know where to start my search for an error.

Example Code: for a spec

```
@Stepwise
class CheckMenuLinks extends Admin {

def "Go to Dashboard"() {
    when:
    at VersionPage
    then:
    mainNavigation.clickMenu("overview","Dashboard")
    waitTestEnd()
}


def "Go to Box Overview / Transactions"() {
    when:
    at DashboardPage
    mainNavigation.clickMenu("overview","Transactions")
    waitTestEnd()
    then:
    at TransactionsPage


}

def "Go to Box Overview / Health"() {
    when:
    at TransactionsPage
    mainNavigation.clickMenu("overview","Health")
    waitTestEnd()
    then:
    at HealthPage


}
```

}

This spec just clicks every link of my menu and checks, if the page is loaded.

Example for a page:

```
class DashboardPage extends LayoutBasePage{
static at = { pageMarker }

static content = {
    pageMarker(wait: true) { $('#pageDashboard') }

}
```

}

Every page has an ID in the body tag. The strange problem is, that the page is loaded correctly, the id is present in the body tag, but the test fails. But just sometimes. And not always on the same step, always another step.

Exception:

```
geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 20.0 seconds (failed with exception)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:138)
at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:226)
at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:182)
at geb.Browser.doAt(Browser.groovy:454)
at geb.Browser.at(Browser.groovy:336)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:56)
at specs.scenario.create.BoxUser.Add New User(BoxUser.groovy:46)
Caused by: geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 20.0 seconds (failed with exception)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:138)
at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create(PageContentTemplate.groovy:74)
at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.get(PageContentTemplate.groovy:54)
at geb.content.DefaultPageContentSupport.getContent(DefaultPageContentSupport.groovy:42)
at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:39)
at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:99)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:321)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyDelegateFirst(Closure.java:311)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
at pages.configuration.boxusers.UserProfilePage._clinit__closure1(UserProfilePage.groovy:7)
at pages.configuration.boxusers.UserProfilePage._clinit__closure1(UserProfilePage.groovy)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:117)
at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:226)
at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:182)
at geb.Browser.doAt(Browser.groovy:454)
at geb.Browser.at(Browser.groovy:336)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:56)
at specs.scenario.create.BoxUser.Add New User(BoxUser.groovy:46)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError: $('#pageSetupUser')
```

Comment: If the element you're checking is loaded dynamically with AJAX, you might need to use 'waitFor'. See http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#waiting
Otherwise, please edit the question to provide more details, including the full exception.

Comment: Hi, I am using (wait: true) for my elements, is this not enought? I will provide example code

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but it's better to use `atCheckWaiting = true` in your Geb config, as described at http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-check-waiting, instead of using `wait: true` on all your "at checkers".

Comment: I have this two options in my gebconfig.groovy: 
atCheckWaiting = true
baseNavigatorWaiting = true

Do I have to use this in the waiting {} section?

Comment: No, those options should be outside of the waiting {} section. I'm out of ideas. In my opinion, there must be some kind of dynamic page loading that gets in your way.

Comment: Is there a command like waitForFinishedLoad  of a dynamic page loading?

Comment: Is there a possibility to wait for page loading has finished?